# How to change some style in Bootstrap Using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I want to know that if I make a navigation bar using Bootstrap and needs to change some style from the default or pre-defined properties then how can I change it?

Comment: By using CSS? :) I don;t really understand your question. Please be more clear.

Comment: If you want to overwrite bootstrap styles, than the order of your css files in your main file is important. Knowing about css specificity might also help, in addition to adding additional classnames to the your html that you want to change the style of. See also https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Add an extra class to the element you want to apply the external css. Like in <nav class="custom"> or in <li class="custom"> Then write css styling for your custom class or id in stylesheet file. Don't forget to include new css file to your html having navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

The first step might to over rule using the `navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse` class and then use your own custom class, i.e. `navbar-style`. Finally, go to your css styles file and then custom the properties for the custom `.navbar-style{}`. All the best

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties directly in the bootstrap CSS file (which is not always the best way to do it) or add a new CSS file where you can override the desired class

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it.

1- Assign custom class to the element and apply styles. For example:

```
    <navbar class="navbar-default navbar-trans">...</navbar>
    <style>
.navbar-trans {background:transparent}
</style>
```

2- Override CSS in custom file. example:

```
.navbar-default{background:transparent}
```

Note: add your css file after the bootstrap CSS file

3- Change style directly in the bootstrap CSS file (not recommended)